# 32 bit Internet Explorer in x64 Vista can't run javascript

Tags: windows-vista, 64-bit, internet-explorer-8

I'm running x64 Vista at work, and I have Internet Explorer 8 installed. My machine is logged onto our work domain.

The 64 bit version of Internet Explorer is working fine, no problems there. Javascript works ok. This simple test in 64bit IE brings up an alert window for me: javascript:alert(document.lastModified)

However, in the 32 bit version of IE, javascript doesn't seem to work at all, on any page. The simple test above does nothing in 32 bit IE.

My IT department is fairly sure that they haven't set any group policies that would disable javascript. No other users seem to have this problem, but nearly all other users here have x32 Vista.

Can anyone explain why javascript might work in 64bit IE but not 32bit IE?

Thanks,

Tubby

Edit: My problem is just with Javascript, not Java.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to work this out in the end by running ProcessMonitor to watch what Internet Explorer was doing when I ran my javascript test. It turned out some registry class keys were missing. Re-registering IEPROXY.DLL fixed that problem.

Comment: totally hectic solution -but well done on finding it :)

Answer (score 0):

Erm... because you installed 64bit Java? the add-on won't work in 64bit IE then, just like how alot of my 32bit Safari extensions won't show up in 64bit Safari (grrr).

EDIT : Found out what actually went wrong with Javascript on your IE 32bit - you must re-register the DLL.

From command line :

*regsvr32.exe jscript.dll*

Comment: But Java and Javascript are entirely separate technologies?

Comment: Oh, I read wrongly. My bad. Check your preferences in IE 32 bit to see if you disabled Javascript?

Comment: Have had a look - in Security Settings, Active scripting is set to Enabled. Do you know if there are any other options that control the enabling of Javascript?

Comment: Sorry, afraid that regsvr32.exe jscript.dll didn't work for me. Registering the DLL succeeded, but 32 bit Iexplore still didn't work. Thanks anyway.